# Creating middleware that does external api call

Tags: node.js, api, express, request

I'm creating a middleware that checks if a JWT token is valid, to do this it needs to call an external API. If the token is valid, it should continue the regular functionality.

Here's the **middleware** I wrote (`then` does not get triggered):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      status: 401,
      message: 'Unauthorized Error: Invalid access token.'
    }).end();
  } else {
    requestify
      .request(process.env.SWF_AUTH_INFO, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept-Language': 'nl',
          Authorization: req.headers.authorization
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.body.valid) {
          next();
        } else {
          return res.status(401).json({
            status: 401,
            message: 'Unauthorized Error: Invalid access token.'
          }).end();
        }
      });
  }
});
```

**My problem:**

Every call I do just stays on `pending`. I don't get any response and I don't get any errors either. All my calls worked perfectly before I wrote the middleware.

Here's how I handle my api requests:

**Route**

```
/**
   * Get all surveys associated with a participant
   *
   * URL: /participant/:id/surveys
   * METHOD: GET
   */
  router.get('/participant/:id/surveys', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.params.id) {
      return res.status(422).send('Participant id of null');
    }
    participantService
      .getSurveys(req.params.id)
      .then(data => {
        res.status(200).send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(422).send(err);
      });
  });
```

**Service:**

```
function getSurveys(participantId) {
  return participantModel.getSurveys(participantId);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function getSurveys(participantId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(
        ...
      ),
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          dbFunc.connectionRelease;
          reject(error);
        } else {
          dbFunc.connectionRelease;
          resolve(result);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Why is my middleware not sending any responses?

Comment: Does your code enter this line? `requestify.request`, maybe the request is throwing an error you are not catching. or the request is not fired at all.

Comment: @RolandStarke yup, it hits the breakpoint there.

Comment: is it goes to the `then` section? before this line `if (response.body.valid) {`?

Comment: idk requestify, maybe it uses a promise library that dosn't care about unhandled errors. (as normaly unhandled promise errors are shown) you could add `.catch(next)`.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty nope it doesn't.

Comment: for requestify it uses the `.fail(..)` callback for handling errors, check if it goes there, https://github.com/ranm8/requestify#handling-errors